# Odd Cygwin netstat output

Tags: windows, cygwin

```
20:38:41 [setevoy@setevoy-main ~] $ netstat -anp

▒▒⨢▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒祭▒▒

  ▒▒▒    ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒        ▒▒▒譨▒ ▒▒▒▒          ▒▒▒▒ﭨ▒
```

I have clear installtion of **Cygwin** on my **Win7** x64 desktop, but `netstat` returns something very-very odd...
What it can be? Can it be caused by **Windows** *Ru* localization? Or something else?

Same output with any options.

All other utils works normally.

```
$ which netstat
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/netstat
```

Comment: can you past the output of "which netstat"

Comment: Oh... Seems I udnerstood... @Raza, could you post to Answer? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are picking the correct `netstat` for your platform. `which netstat` will give you path where it is executing it from.